# Facebook Real time for Feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook Realtime Updates API... I have the following code :

```
<?php

define('VERIFY_TOKEN', '*');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') {

    $hostname = "*";
    $username = "*";
    $dbname = "*";
    $password = "*";

    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    $post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $object = json_decode($post_body, true);

    foreach ($object->entry as $update) {
        // For each entry in notification, insert a row of information into the table "FaceBook"
        $changed_fields = $update->changed_fields[0];
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO FaceBook (uid, id, time, changed_fields) VALUES('$update->uid', '$update->id', '$update->time', '$changed_fields')")
                or die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Now, when an update occurs, facebook is sending a POST request, but the foreach loop is not being entered... i tried to check if the $object is empty, but it returns 2 elements (using count)..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues with this as well.

Every object has a number of entries. Every entry can have a few changes I believe. So "changes" is also an array like entries do.

Try this:

```
foreach($object->entry as $update){

    foreach($update->changes as $change){

        //access information about the change that occured on the page

    }
}
```